# My App received nil Data during a HTTPS URLSessionDataTask

Tags: ios, json, swift3, cfnetwork, nsurlsessiondatatask

My iOS application's view controller simply GET requests a JSON from my backend API server using Swift 3 code and Foundation classes URL, URLRequest, URLSessionDataTask.

My backend API server (sesapi.infinnovation.co) supports HTTPS over TLS 1.2 and works perfectly both on IPv4, IPv6 networks (Hence, the backend server is fully ATS-compilant (App Transport Security) ). My app was rejected by Apple App Review because the when the App Review board used my app build it showed a no internet connection prompt.

When I use Xcode to deploy my app in my iOS device it is working absolutely fine and there are no network errors. But, when my app builds are submitted to iTunesConnect post app archiving on Xcode the app receives "nil" as JSON data and hence network error prompt is shown. I used NSLog and TestFlight to fetch some crucial logging info and here is the log.

[iOS Log shows TIC TCP handshake complete yet no json received from network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXlwo.png) 
(NSLog will output nil JSON when no data is received from network otherwise it'll output the JSON string itself)

When I try .ipa archive exports using Ad-Hoc or using TestFlight builds even then my app fails to work and no internet is shown.

My app project is currently open-source and I had issued an Apple TSI in this regard but even they couldn't help. How do I fix my app and get it running to the store with immediate effect.
[App Project on GitHub](https://github.com/swghosh/infinnovation-stock-exchange-simulator-ios-app)

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. I've tried a lot of ways and consulted many to solve this issue but all in vain.
Thanks in advance.